# JSON dump non-numeric floats with Python's ujson module

Tags: python, json, nan, dump, infinity

I'm trying to serialize numbers using `ujson` module in Python3. Some of the values are `NaN`s.

When using the standard `json` module, everything works fine.

```
import json
json.dumps(float('NaN'))
```

gives:

```
'NaN'
```

But there is a problem with `ujson`.

```
import ujson
ujson.dumps(float('NaN'))
```

throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OverflowError: Invalid Nan value when encoding double
```

I'm using `ujson` for performance reasons. Do I have to replace all the occurrences of `NaN` in my structures with the string `'NaN'`, or is there a way to tell `ujson` to handle `NaN`s without throwing an exception?

I also have the very same issues with infinities. I was unable to find any relevant docs.

Comment: See e.g. https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/80; this is actually *more consistent* with the JSON specification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627) that defines the JSON format, in section *2.4* about numbers:

> Numeric values that cannot be represented as sequences of digits (such as *Infinity* and *NaN*) are not permitted.

So `ujson` is more compliant with JSON standard then the `json` module in standard library. According to me this result unnecessarily pedantic, but the choice of `ujson` is to conform to this standard. You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/esnme/ultrajson/issues/80).

It seems that the only way is to convert the data before (or submit a pull request to `ujson` to enable it).